# binding data to the treelist control

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, datasource, xtratreelist

I'm having one table which contains the field as "IsBulitIn" & which is of bit type. Depending on the field value i filtered my table & i got to set of data . I used dataview for each type of data. Now i'm having two dataview's . I want to create two parent nodes at run time . The name may be "BuiltIn Group" & "My Group". & i want to set these two dataviews to the my above two parent node.

Is it possible by to set the datasource property to the each parent node?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, there is a way to do this, though this way is not a straight forward.  First, I should tell, that the TreeListNode class does not provide the DataSource property.  So, it is impossible to just set a property and achieve the required effect.  Anyway, I would suggest that you create child nodes for these nodes yourself:

```
void PopulateNodes(TreeListNode parentNode, DataView dataView) { 
            treeList1.BeginUnboundLoad();
            try {
                for(int i = 0; i < dataView.Count; i++) {
                    treeList1.AppendNode(new object[] { dataView[i]["SomeFieldName"] }, parentNode);
                }
            }
            finally {
                treeList1.EndUnboundLoad();
            }
        }
```

To add a parent node programmatically, use the following code:

```
    TreeListNode parentNode = treeList1.AppendNode(new object[] { "parent" }, null);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.I've used the same technique. But when we add the nodes in this way then i think it is unbound technique of data adding. Can we add parent node pro-grammatically in the treelist?